# How to share one AJAX call between two stores?

Tags: extjs4, store

I have two Sencha/ExtJS4 grids which use the exact same data (ie, same store.proxy.url), but each uses different filters, so each has its own separate store.  The problem is I am making an unnecessary AJAX call to retrieve the extra copy to work with.

What is the recommended approach to make a single AJAX call and then share the data between two stores, for independent filtering?

potential solutions:

- create two classes that extend the same store ?
- use the same proxy instance ?
- retrieve one store then cloning it ?

Comment: Personally i would clone the store. You can also play with your filters (set/unset/reset) some of them to retrieve desirable result just if you don't have to show two of different results at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ext JS 4 framework seems to be built with the intention that each view receives its own store. As mentioned in other answers, your best option is to create a second store and copy all the records from one to the other.

```
function cloneStore(src, dest) {
    var recs = src.getRange(); // returns array of records
    dest.loadRecords(recs);  // removes existing records before batch add
}
```

The exact implementation of that function may vary depending on how you need your data spread out. If each grid only needs a subset of the data to begin with, you can initialize a master store from your Ajax call, then create two sub-stores using filters directly on the store.data MixedCollection.

```
// Note: This function isn't exactly "good practice"
// Actual implementation may vary
function populateSubStores(master, storeA, storeB) {
    var dataA = master.data.filter(/* filter criteria for store A */),
        dataB = master.data.filter(/* filter criteria for store B */);
    // dataA and dataB are MixedCollections of records
    storeA.loadRecords(dataA.getRange());
    storeB.loadRecords(dataB.getRange());
}
```

Or some variation thereof. This should be enough to get you started in the right direction.

If you're really gung-ho, you could create a new type of store that maintains separate MixedCollections representing filter states from different views, then return each filter state as a store with an identical interface to `Ext.data.Store` but with an implementation that operates on the "master" store's internal representation so that existing views can operate without overrides. But I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two instances of one store and then just copy data from one store to another using `getRange()` and `add()` methods. Creating two classes doesn't seem reasonable.